# In the meantime, how do I get executable coverage with stack?

Tags: haskell, code-coverage, haskell-stack

My program consists of 4 executables, and basically zero library code.  My tests work by running the executables with various input files.

"stack test --coverage" apparently doesn't handle executables.  OK, fine, but I can't figure out how to do it "by hand", as it were.

I've tried adding -fhpc to my cabal files, and it appears to work:

```
  /home/rlpowell/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc -B/home/rlpowell/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1 --make -no-link -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -static -outputdir .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/unphone/unphone-tmp -odir .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/unphone/unphone-tmp -hidir .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/unphone/unphone-tmp -stubdir .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/unphone/unphone-tmp -i -i.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/unphone/unphone-tmp -iapp -i.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/autogen -I.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/autogen -I.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/unphone/unphone-tmp -optP-include -optP.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -hide-all-packages -no-user-package-db -package-db /home/rlpowell/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.4/8.0.1/pkgdb -package-db /dropbox/src/hblog/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-7.4/8.0.1/pkgdb -package-db .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.0.0/package.conf.inplace -package-id base-4.9.0.0 -package-id directory-1.2.6.2 -package-id filemanip-0.3.6.3-DFENeGbODv96RwGywUxkEu -package-id filepath-1.4.1.0 -package-id hblog-0.1.0.0-5BseEsncIi47yHhFL2tGbM -package-id pcre-heavy-1.0.0.2-ncNpc9J5vG8YMUKvU47xG -package-id pcre-light-0.4.0.4-IQAaYrFkWFB49U9V8o5b8j -package-id unix-2.7.2.0 -XHaskell2010 app/unphone.hs -threaded -Wall -fhpc -Wall -fhpc -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file
```

but after running the programs thus generated, I can't find a .hpc directory or any .tix files.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in [the documentation for `--coverage`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/latest/coverage/) (may only apply to current dev version of stack)?

Comment: If there is, I don't get it.

Comment: Ok, I'm not very familiar with stack's coverage functionality. I suggest you make a feature request on the [stack issue tracker](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues), ideally with a sample project that can be used to reproduce the issue. That should also have a good chance of producing a temporary workaround for you.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer the .hpc files ended up in `.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/hpc/` and the .tix file was in the working directory.

This is a bash script I use for testing an executable with no library code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
stack build --coverage
stack exec tests

while getopts ":r" opt; do
    case $opt in
        r)
            hpc markup --hpcdir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/hpc/ --destdir=coverage_markup tests.tix
            firefox coverage_markup/hpc_index.html
            sleep 120
    esac
done

rm -rf coverage_markup
rm tests.tix
```